# where is the section in the standard regarding "virtual function call in base constructor"

Tags: c++, standards

Virtual function calls inside a base constructor invoke the one of the base, not of the derived classes.

In which section does the iso-cpp standard discuss this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$12.7/4 Construction and destruction [class.cdtor] (bold by me)

> Member functions, including virtual functions (10.3), can be called
>   during construction or destruction (12.6.2). When a virtual function
>   is called directly or indirectly from a constructor or from a
>   destructor, including during the construction or destruction of the
>   class’s non-static data members, and the object to which the call
>   applies is the object (call it x) under construction or destruction,
>   **the function called is the final overrider in the constructor’s or
>   destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class.**
>   If the virtual function call uses an explicit class member access
>   (5.2.5) and the object expression refers to the complete object of x
>   or one of that object’s base class subobjects but not x or one of its
>   base class subobjects, the behavior is undefined. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct V {
>   virtual void f();
>   virtual void g();
> };
> struct A : virtual V {
>   virtual void f();
> };
> struct B : virtual V {
>   virtual void g();
>   B(V*, A*);
> };
> struct D : A, B {
>   virtual void f();
>   virtual void g();
>   D() : B((A*)this, this) { }
> };
> B::B(V* v, A* a) {
>   f(); // calls V::f, not A::f
>   g(); // calls B::g, not D::g
>   v->g(); // v is base of B, the call is well-defined, calls B::g
>   a->f(); // undefined behavior, a’s type not a base of B
> }
> ```
>
> —end example ]